# Syntax meaning in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, syntax

Can someone please explain to me the meaning of the first parentheses in the following statement:

```
Window* win= (main_window*) glfwGetWindowUserPointer(main_window);
```

Comment: It is a C-style cast. Get a good textbook.

Comment: You have a Window pointer set equal to the function return casted to a main_Window pointer.

Comment: Note that Window* can be equal to a main_window probably because Window is the base class

Answer (score 1):

Casting in C. Means that memory you get from function will be casted to `main_window` type of your structure or class you have.

This will help compiler to know everything about your data offsets in structure or class. It will also prevent any warnings from compiler.

This will be later assigned to win variable.